# Apache2 and php7.0 get blanc page

Tags: apache2, php7

I've search the site for answers but didn't find a solution to my problem.

Here is the situation:

I have a fresh install of the latest ubuntu :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

with apache2 and php7 installed and running.
I've enable the php7.0 module :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
apache2                                         install
apache2-bin                                     install
apache2-data                                    install
apache2-utils                                   install
libapache2-mod-php                              install
libapache2-mod-php7.0                           install
```

my apache2 sites-available configuration :

```
DocumentRoot /opt/Test/Sources

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /opt/Test/Sources>
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my directories :

```
ll
total 12
drwxrwxrwx  3 root     root     4096 Nov 14 16:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root     root     4096 Nov 16 16:35 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 16:42 Test/

cd Test/
ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 16:42 ./
drwxrwxrwx 3 root     root     4096 Nov 14 16:41 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 16:42 Images/
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 16 18:13 Sources/

cd Sources/
ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 27 18:22 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 16:42 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   19 Nov 16 18:07 index.php*
```

I've made a simple test file in index.php :

```
<?

phpinfo();

?>
```

But when I browse, I get a blanc page. When I check the source code in the browser I get what my index.php has :

```
<?

phpinfo();

?>
```

It look's like apache doesn't interpret the file. error.log has no error and access.log look's normal :

```
192.168.70.88 - - [27/Nov/2016:18:27:43 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 223 "-"         "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
192.168.70.88 - - [27/Nov/2016:18:27:43 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "http://192.168.70.30/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
```

Does someone has an Idea ? It's been a long time I haven't worked with apache and php, I've probably forgoten something.

Many thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.

In this version of php, in the /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini by default the short_open_tag = Off.
That mean's the lines

```
<?

?>
```

are not recognize as php code and there for not processed.
you can either enable short tags or add a "php" at the end of the first line

and it works.